# Executing binary file from uDeploy sh script

Tags: shell, udeploy

I have a binary file say "x" and when I execute it from terminal it does some stuff and waits for user to enter "\" and "enter key" to exit. I execute this binary(x) file like below an it works perfectly fine.

```
./x
```

My requirement is that I need to execute this binary from a uDeploy shell script. This uDeploy script will be executed whenever it is required. Below mentioned is uDeploy shell script content to execute binary:

```bash
echo "Start"
cd /home/script
./x
echo "End"
```

Problem I am facing is, from terminal binary execution works fine but when I execute uDeploy script which internally executes the binary file does not do anything. When I execute the above uDeploy script I get the below output

```
Start
End
```

What am I missing here ?

Comment: Please format code properly - fixed width font, and each code line in a l ine of its own.

Comment: If the shell were encountering an error trying to start the binary, you'd have an error message written to stderr. If the `x` executable has conditional behavior -- if, say, it only writes logs when attached to a TTY -- that's something that right now nobody but you has access to the executable to inspect.

Comment: One place to start is to make sure that stderr is actually being logged somewhere you can read it. Another is to log exit status -- say, `./x || { rc=$?; echo "$x exited with status $rc" >&2; exit "$rc"; }`

Comment: And not related to your question, but as a matter of good practice, don't run `sh yourscript`. Just run `./yourscript`, after making sure the script has execute permission and starts with a shebang that specifies which shell to run with -- if it's supposed to be run with `sh`, for example, that might be `#!/bin/sh` as the first line. That way if in the future you want to use bash-only features you can change `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/usr/bin/env bash` and you don't need to change the code that _starts_ your script to from `sh yourscript` to `bash yourscript`.

Comment: With respect to inspecting executable behavior at runtime, by the way -- on Linux, `strace -o x.strace -f -s 2048 ./x` will create a file `x.strace` you can read to see what `x` did while it was being run.

Comment: (Mind, `sh ./x` doesn't work if `x` is a binary file -- it only works if `x` is a script -- so I assume you're mistaken when you say you run `sh /home/script/x` successfully)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yes you are correct I am running the binary as first `cd to /home/script/` then `./x` from the terminal

Comment: Then what did you mean when you said "I execute this binary(x) file like below an it works perfectly fine." with the "below" example being `sh ./x`? That's not the same as running `./x` in `sh` (it _would_ be like `sh -c './x'`, but the `-c` is critical).

Comment: ok let me explain. I am executing the file(x) as ./x from the terminal and works fine. It waits for user to type - "\\" and "enter" to get exited from the script (that is the behavior of the script execution)
when I am executing the same command from uDeploy script it does nothing. Hope I was able to explain.